# when i enter data in .mdf file using below code there is no error but in database not display data

Tags: visual-studio-2008

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    ''cmd.CommandText = "insert into data values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into  db1(id,name) values ( '" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a WinForm or ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 0):

It is a common scenario that hits hard on newbie.

You use the |DataDirectory| substitution string.

In a WinForms application the string is equivalent to the directory where your app runs. When you run inside Visual Studio this directory is the BIN\DEBUG folder (Or x86 variant).

But, if you look at your MDF file using the internal Visual Studio Server Explorer then you are probably using a different connection string. A connection string that points at your MDF file located in the current project folder. Of course this file has not been changed by the execution of your debug session.

I suggest to create a second connection string in the Server Explorer window. This connection should point to the MDF file in your BIN\DEBUG folder. Keep the first just for database schema changes and the second for checking the effective work of your application

Also, if you have listed your MDF file between your project items, remember to change the property `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`